# If/Elseif statement in PHP

Tags: php, html, if-statement

We are trying to create an if/elseif statement for the variable `$day`.  We defined the variable and its values in the HTML code associated with this PHP.  I will paste the PHP section to this page. The problem is that the results page is only giving the response for "$day = 1". Does anyone know of an error in this code that would cause this to happen? We also tried using two equals signs but that made it worse!

```
echo "<p>";
                if ($day = 1) {
                    echo "Sunday Funday! What COMMITMENT to going out!";
                } elseif ($day = 2) {
                    echo "The start of what's sure to be a rough week. Drink away your sorrows.";
                } elseif ($day = 3) {
                    echo "Epic night! SO many themes at the bars!";
                } elseif ($day = 4) {
                    echo "Hump day!! But seriously, what are you doing...? Aren't you too hungover from last night?";
                } elseif ($day = 5) {
                    echo "Thirsty Thursday!! It's close enough to the weekend... right?";
                } elseif ($day = 6) {
                    echo "It's Friiiiiiday, Friiiiiiiday, Gotta get down on Friiiiiiiiiday!";
                } elseif ($day = 7) {
                    echo "It's FRATurday! Go have some fun!";

            }
```

Comment: You definitely need 2 equals signs as = is assignment

Comment: you want to use if/else specifically? it is better to use switch in like this case,

Comment: You do need to use `==`. What do you mean by "made it worse"?

Comment: Seems like you need to spend less time at the bars and more time with your code ;)

Comment: First `=` is a assignment operator and `==` is a conditional operator that is to be used in `if`. Also for your logic `switch/case` approach would me more appropriate.

Answer (score 8):

You are using assignment `=` when you mean to use comparison `==`.

Assignment evaluates to what is at the right hand side, so

```
if ($day = 1)
```

is the same as

```
if (1)
```

which due to [these rules](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php#language.types.boolean.casting) is the same as

```
if (true)
```

This should explain why the program behaves like it does and of course you now know how to fix it. But it would be even better if you used a `switch` statement:

```
switch($day) {
    case 1:
        echo "Sunday Funday! What COMMITMENT to going out!";
        break;
    case 2:
        echo "The start of what's sure to be a rough week.";
        break;
    // etc etc
}
```

Comment: When we add two equals signs, the entire echo statement disappears from the results page.

Comment: Then the problem is obviously not the comparison, but the fact that `$day` does not equal any of the values you are testing against. You can use `var_dump($day)` to see what it actually is.

Answer (score 6):

Your are assigning (`=`). You need a logical equality (`==`).

```
if ($day == 1) {
  echo "Sunday Funday! What COMMITMENT to going out!";
}
```

Check out [comparison](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) and [logical operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php). Also the [`switch()` statement](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php).

Answer (score 6):

If you have a long list of conditions to check against, you do not typically want to write a long chain of if / else statements. Rather try a [`switch`](http://php.net/switch) block, or even an [`array`](http://php.net/array) map:

```
 $map = array(
    1 => "Sunday Funday! What COMMITMENT to going out!",
    2 => "The start of what's sure to be a rough week. Drink away your sorrows.",
    3 => "Epic night! SO many themes at the bars!",
    4 => "...",
 );
```

As then the code becomes pretty simple:

```
 echo $map[ $day ];
```

(Ideally would use an [`isset`](http://php.net/isset) check. But for the development stage PHP is clever enough to give hints about missing entries. If the input values are already constrained/asserted, no need anyway.)

Answer (score 2):

The comparison operator is `==` and not `=`.

Also try this lookup table approach, which is cleaner in this situation:

```
$day_msg = array(
    1 => "Sunday Funday! What COMMITMENT to going out!",
    2 => "The start of what's sure to be a rough week. Drink away your sorrows.",
    3 => "Epic night! SO many themes at the bars!",
    4 => "Hump day!! But seriously, what are you doing...? Aren't you too hungover from last night?",
    5 => "Thirsty Thursday!! It's close enough to the weekend... right?"
    6 => "It's Friiiiiiday, Friiiiiiiday, Gotta get down on Friiiiiiiiiday!",
    7 => "It's FRATurday! Go have some fun!"
);
echo "<p>";
echo $day_msg[$day];
```

Answer (score 2):

you want to make all  the conditions like this

```
            if ($day == 1) {
                echo "Sunday Funday! What COMMITMENT to going out!";
            } elseif ($day == 2) {
                echo "The start of what's sure to be a rough week. Drink away your sorrows.";
            } elseif ($day == 3) {
                echo "Epic night! SO many themes at the bars!";
            } elseif ($day == 4) {
                echo "Hump day!! But seriously, what are you doing...? Aren't you too hungover from last night?";
            } elseif ($day == 5) {
                echo "Thirsty Thursday!! It's close enough to the weekend... right?";
            } elseif ($day == 6) {
                echo "It's Friiiiiiday, Friiiiiiiday, Gotta get down on Friiiiiiiiiday!";
            } elseif ($day == 7) {
                echo "It's FRATurday! Go have some fun!";

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You're first thought was right, you need the **two** equal signs.